# Use gulp files from other npm packages (import files which will eventually exist)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have one npm package containing several files with several gulp task definitions.

What I want is in the main gulpfile, be able to copy these gulp files (from the package) and execute the gulp tasks defined in them.

Follows an example:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const gulpFolder = path.join(__dirname.replace('gulpfile.js', ''), 'src', 'generated-code', 'gulp'); 

const cleanGulpFiles = (callback) => { ... }

const copyGulpFiles = (callback) => {
    gulp.src(`${nodeModulesFolder}/@primavera/client-app-core/gulp/**/*`)
        .pipe(chmod(666))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(gulpFolder));
    callback();
}

exports.debug = gulp.series(
    cleanGulpFiles, 
    copyGulpFiles,
    require('../src/generated-code/gulp/gulp.debug'));
```

The problem is: When I try to execute `gulp debug`, it is retrieved an error saying `require('../src/generated-code/gulp/gulp.debug')` does not exists. And it is right because this file will be only available when the task `copyGulpFiles` is done.

Anyone knows a workaround to do what I want to accomplish?

Comment: May be https://nshki.com/es6-in-gulp-projects/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround that I found was to combine [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) functions in order to read the gulp file content as a string and then evaluate that code in run time:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const gulpFolder = path.join(__dirname.replace('gulpfile.js', ''), 'src', 'generated-code', 'gulp'); 

const cleanGulpFiles = (callback) => { ... }

const copyGulpFiles = (callback) => {
    gulp.src(`${nodeModulesFolder}/@primavera/client-app-core/gulp/**/*`)
        .pipe(chmod(666))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(gulpFolder));
    callback();
}

const executeGulpFiles = (callback) => {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('../src/generated-code/gulp/gulp.debug');
    const contentEvaluated = eval(fileContent);
    contentEvaluated(callback);
}

exports.debug = gulp.series(
    cleanGulpFiles, 
    copyGulpFiles,
    executeGulpFiles);
```